# ngx-pagination in Angular 4. How to get page number?

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I using Angular 4 and Typescript with library ngx-pagination. I a bit don't understand this library. I have paggination in Java and I want to send page number when page is changed. Numbers of all items came from Java site. I don't know how to handle this problem. I created this code:
In html:

```
<tr *ngFor="let story of stories | paginate: { itemsPerPage: this.size, currentPage: this.page, totalItems: this.numberOfElements }" style="text-align: left; word-break: break-all;">

<pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChange.emit($event)"></pagination-controls>
```

and in TS I created this:

```
@Output() pageChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter();
```

And now how to get page when I change it e.g. when I click on next or Previous?

Comment: is the pagination not working ?

Comment: No it doesn't work. Numbers of pages display properly but i can't change the page

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have this in the **template**

```
<pagination-controls (pageChange)="page = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

and in the **component** have a class level variable just denoting the page like   `page: number = 1;`
 .

**UPDATE**

you can use this in **template** `(pageChange)="pageChanged($event)"`

in **component**

```
pageChanged(event){console.log("pageChanged")}
```

Comment: It's working but how can I know when page is changed?

Comment: @Rahul Singh: I have integrated the server side pagination. Data returned from API call. Here total number of pages as infinity. Pagination call is *ngFor="let deals of dealslist  | paginate: { id: 'foo',
                                                      itemsPerPage: pageSize,
                                                      currentPage: p,
                                                      totalItems: count }". Controls as     <pagination-controls (pageChange)="pageChanged($event)" id="foo"></pagination-controls>

Comment: @SamHanson what is the exact issue

Comment: How to get the lastpage number